# How to say 'playthrough' in Spanish

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico

Earlier I was making some attempts to talk with others online about a video game using my not very great Spanish when I realized I had no idea how to say 'playthrough', I just went with 'guardada' instead, which to my understanding would be something along the lines of 'save file', which I think (hope!) would convey the idea fine.

Anyways back to the point, how would you say 'playthrough'? I thought about just saying 'juego', since in English if you say 'game' instead of 'playthrough' it will typically still make sense.

Just to make sure we're all on the same page, a playthrough is a noun for one time playing through a video game. For example, if you had beaten the game before and were going to start all over and play it again you might say "I'm starting a new playthrough."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the word you are looking for is ***partida***, but I don't think it conveys the same meaning as *playthrough*.

*Partida* is just a synonym for *juego*, which is *game* as you know. So when a videogame prompts you to

> Start a new game

You can translate that in Spanish as:

> Empezar un nuevo juego.
>   Empezar una nueva partida.

Maybe *partida* is more used when the game is suitable for two or more players at the same time and the game is planned to end quickly:

> ¿Echamos unas partidas al Mario Kart?

But when the game is long, with savegames and you are going to continue from where you left last time, you probably say something like

> Voy a seguir con el Dark Souls.
>   Voy a jugar un rato al Dark Souls.

But now we have the word *playthrough* which I understand it means "to play a game from start to end", even if it is a long one. When you complete a long game you usually say in Spanish:

> Acabo de pasarme el Halo.

This means that you beat the game. So in Spanish if you want to say "I'm starting a new playthrough" you can say ***voy a pasarme el juego [otra vez]***.

Comment: That works for the specific example given, but it's also common to see, for instance, video titles in YouTube that are just "Super Mario RPG: Full Playthrough (Part 1)". In that context I'd probably say "juego entero/completo" or maaaybe with "jugada" to emphasize it's not a download link haha.

Comment: I agree with you that *partida* doesn't work for a game played by one person.

Comment: i think FULL PLAYTHROUGH is a pleonasm, a playthrough is a game played from beggining to end, so there's no one word translation for this idea in spanish

Comment: @aparente001 I disagree with you: "partida" is perfectly fine for a single player video-game. I think that "voy a pasarme el juego otra vez" is a great choice.

Comment: @RubioRic - Okay, good to know.  (The marathon video solitaire game world is completely foreign to me.)

Comment: @Mike if you don't finish the whole playthrough but only part of it you'd still call it a playthrough, you'd say something like "I started a new playthrough but got bored halfway through and quit".

Comment: @DJSpicyDeluxe i'm not saying that a playthrough has to be completed, but the word playthrough already inidcates that you are talking about an activity from beggining to end 

a pleonasm is when you are saying the same thing two times: 
saying didn't finish the whole playthrough is the same as saying "didn't finish the playthorugh"

Answer (score 0):

**Ronda**

> Voy a empezar otra ronda.

Meaning, I'm going to start another round.  I think your fellow players will understand this well.

I don't live in the video game world, but this is the term I would use in the sit-across-the-table-from-the-opponents game world.

Documentation: [DRAE](https://dle.rae.es/?id=WgOt7Rx) says: *7. f. En varios juegos de naipes, vuelta o suerte de todos los jugadores.*  [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/spanish-english/ronda) says: *5. [de cartas] hand, game*.

Comment: A round could work for board/card games and short video games meant to be done in one sitting, but I think for a game which takes hours to complete and isn't expected to be done all at once it might not be the best terminology, at least in English.

Comment: @DJSpicyDeluxe - Oh god, it takes hours to complete?  It boggles the mind.  I guess, then, your sentence could be *Voy a empezar otra vez, Vamos de nuevo, Otra vez, muchachos, Ahí vamos de nuevo, Dale otra vez,* or if the person has a music background they could say *Da capo, a ver si [something about what we're hoping to accomplish this time around].*

Comment: The game I was talking about takes 20-30 hours to complete, there are games that take a lot more too.